# Exterior spackle for skim coating (old, cracked) painted wood siding?

Tags: exterior, spackling-paste, wood-filler

I'm under the impression that, because wood expands and contracts significantly, esp. when subject to large variations in temperature and moisture levels, there are really NO reliable skim coat exterior spackling compounds.  Some can be sanded - but that implies that they're probably a lot harder/more rigid that the underlying wood and are thus liable to cracking and flaking off.  (For example: DAP Platinum, Zinsser MH Ready Patch, Synkoloid Exterior Spackling Paste, etc., and two-part filler systems like Abatron, Sculptwood, Bondo, etc.).  The rest are elastomeric (e.g. DAP Flexall and ElastoPatch, various caulks, etc.), but they can't be sanded and thus are quite difficult to apply properly.

Have I got this right...that exterior skim coating is a fool's errand?  Or do products exist that, when properly applied to a well-prepped wood surface and covered with high quality paint, really CAN last for a long, long time?

Comment: Putting a skim coat over a wood surface (particularly outdoors) seems unusual to me. What end result are you trying to achieve by using the skim cost here?

Comment: Prepping and painting wood on a regular basis is one of the joys of having wood siding. The better the prep job and the higher the quality of paint, the longer you'll go between paint jobs, but it's still going to require ongoing maintenance. That's why people put vinyl/aluminum siding over it - they get tired of the maintenance effort & cost. I'd think that if there were a stucco/spackle compound that would work and last significantly longer than just painting wood, people would already be using it.

Comment: brhans, I'm just trying to iron out a host of relatively low profile irregularities and obtain a smooth surface.  I can either sand down the cracks and stipples, or (theoretically, at least) fill/cover over them with a thin layer of exterior spackle.  My question is whether the latter is a realistic option, or will just bring me grief over time.

Comment: My intuition is that sanding is both faster and more effective than any kind of filling. (One pass with the sander should be sufficient, then prime/paint. Compare to any kind of filler, which you apply, wait to dry, return to sand at least once, then prime/paint.)

Comment: Aloysius,  Actually, that makes a ton of sense!  Thanks.